# Any way to stick header on UICollectionView while dragging

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have sticked the section of the `UICollectionView` using frame and zindex. I am using custom layout [CustomCollectionViewLayout](http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns).

Issue is that when i drag the section and drop down to the last, while scrolling there is flicker in the sticked sections. I am using `LongPressGesture` to drag the section.

1.I think if i get answers to below questions it might help:

2.How to disable scrolling in the some sections?

3.Any other way to stick the header (section) to top without using
    supplementaryView?

4.How can i refresh views constantly while i am dragging cell in
       changed state of `LongPressGesture`?